# Estimating $\prod_{p\mid n}(1+1/p)$ in terms of n

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $n\geq 1$ be an integer,  $P$ the set of rational prime numbers. I am interested in upper bounds for $\prod_{p\in P; \ p\mid n}(1+1/p)$ in terms of n.

I would like to find explicit real numbers $a,b$ such that for any integer $n\geq 1$ it holds $\prod_{p\in P; \ p\mid n}(1+1/p)\leq a\log(n)^b$.

By the answer of GH this is possible for any $b>0$ provided $n$ is **sufficiently large**.

Now, I would like to find **explicit** real numbers $a,c$ such that for **any** integer $n\geq 10$ it holds $\prod_{p\in P; \ p\mid n}(1+1/p)\leq a\log(n)+c$.

What are small possible values for $c$ and $a$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a weaker bound that is completely explicit, the following method is pretty simple. Let $\omega(n)$ denote the number of distinct prime factors of $n$. Since the function $1+1/x$ is a decreasing function of $x$, and the smallest prime equals 2, we certainly have
$$
\prod_{p\mid n} \bigg( 1+\frac1p \bigg) \le \prod_{k=2}^{\omega(n)+1} \bigg( 1+\frac1k \bigg) = \frac{\omega(n)+2}2
$$
since the product telescopes. Moreover, $\omega(n) \le (\log n)/(\log 2)$, again since each prime factor of $n$ is at least 2. Therefore
$$
\prod_{p\mid n} \bigg( 1+\frac1p \bigg) \le \frac{\log n}{2\log2}+1
$$
(with equality at $n=1$ and $n=2$).

Comment: This completely answers my question, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to verify that for sufficiently large $n$
$$ \sum_{p\mid n}\frac{1}{p}<\sum_{p<2\log n}\frac{1}{p}<\log\log\log n+O(1) $$
whence
$$ \prod_{p\mid n} \left( 1+\frac{1}{p} \right) \ll \log\log n.$$
In other words, you can choose any $b>0$. Also, one can further refine the above bound.

Comment: Indeed, for any constant $C>6e^\gamma/\pi^2$ (where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant), we have
$$
\prod_{p\mid n}\bigg(1+\frac1p\bigg) < C\log\log n
$$
for all $n>n_0(C)$. And this is best possible, in that there are infinitely many violations if $C<6e^\gamma/\pi^2$. One proof uses the identity
$$
\prod_{p\mid n} \bigg(1+\frac1p \bigg) = \frac n{\phi(n)} \prod_{p\mid n} \bigg(1-\frac1{p^2} \bigg)
$$
together with known lower bounds for $\phi(n)$.

Comment: Thanks, Greg, I did not know the exact value of the constant. Do you know a reference off hand?

Comment: Dear GH and Greg Martin, thank you very much for answering my questions.

Comment: GH: Schonfeld and Rosser, updated by Dusart and others.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Prime Functions" Paseman, 2013.03.08

Comment: @GH: liminf phi(n) loglog n / n = e^(-gamma) is for example in Hardy&Wright (Theorem 328).   